# Printing custom ranges or items in Word 2010 using VBA

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am fairly new to VBA (Word 2010) and I'm unsure if something I'd like to do is even possible in the way that I want to do it, or if I need to investigate completely different avenues. I want to be able to print ranges (or items) that are not currently enumerated as part of either wdPrintOutRange or wdPrintOutItem. Is it possible to define a member of a wd enumeration?

As an example, I'd like to be able to print comments by a particular user. wdPrintComments is a member of the wdPrintOutItem enumeration, but, I only want comments that have an Initial value of JQC. Can I define a wdPrintCommentsJQC constant? My code is reasonably simple; I have a userform that lets the user pick some settings (comments by user, endnotes only, etc.) and a Run button whose Click event should generate a PrintOut method with the proper attributes. Am I on the wrong track?

(If it matters, the Initial values will be known to me as I write the code. I have a discrete list.)

Answer (score 2):

No, it's not possible to add a constant to a predefined enumeration type.
However, one possible way to do this would be to build a string of page numbers which contain the items you wish to print, open the print dialog in the "dialogs" collection, and set it to print a specified range, andinsert the string containing the list of pages (separate them with commas).  Finally, execute the .show method of the print dialog to show it to the user and give them the opportunity to set any other items and click the "ok" button.  I've done something very similar when I needed to print a specific chapter of a long document, and so I had to specify the "from" section and page and the "to" section and page for the user.  Below I just show how to specify a list of pages instead of the ".form" and "to" I was using:

```
With Dialogs(wdDialogFilePrint)
  .Range = wdPrintRangeOfPages
  .Pages = "3,5,7-11"
  .show
end with
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. I really can't print the pages; I have to just print the comments. I'll keep plugging away at the problem and post here if I find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how you want to print the comments (or other elements), but you could create another document and insert what you want to print on this document.

According to what you want, you could insert them as they were (comments, footnotes, etc) or as plain text, or any other format.